# Kileの日本語の文字の大きさの設定について

Tags: latex

latex編集ソフトのKileを使っているのですが、タイトルやセクションの文字の大きさが日本語だと本文のそれと変わらず、英語だとちゃんと変わるという問題が起きています。

文字の大きさの直接の変更（\fontsizeなど）でも同じことになるんです。

いろいろ調べたのですが原因がよくわかりません。
何が問題なのでしょうか？

以下、設定を記します。

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{jsarticle}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{ascmac}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines=true,frame=single}
\usepackage[scale=0.76]{geometry}
\usepackage{exscale}



\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pxjahyper}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{otf}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
```

回答お願いします！

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10176392890

Answer (score 1):

CJKutf8 パッケージが悪さをしているようです．このパッケージは pdfLaTeX で CJK 文字（中国語，日本語，韓国語の文字）を出したいときには必要ですが，pLaTeX 使用時にはそもそも不要なので

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
```

を削除するかコメントアウトしてください．